# Neo4j: Exception handling and explict invoking of failure()/close()?

Tags: neo4j

I am trying to handle exceptions in a Neo4j try transaction.

```
try(Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx()) {
    // more code
    tx.sucess();
}
```

The code I posted is standard, it keeps the transaction in variable `tx` and upon the end of the try block `tx.close()` will automatically be called.

Hows does one handle exceptions in this type of block? I know the following works:

```
Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx();
try{
    // more code
    tx.sucess(); // must always be called like so
} catch(Exception e) {
    tx.failure(); // as an exception arised, would be best to call this.
} finally {
    tx.close(); // is tx.close called automatically, or must I call it like I did here?
}
```

So really I have two questions, the first sample of code: how does one handle exceptions in that one?
Second sample of code: what must I call explicitly and what is automatically called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add the exception handling, but omit the finally:

```
try(Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx()) {
    // more code
    tx.sucess();
} catch(Exception e) {
    // ..
}
```